# Horizontal Scrollbar missing from Infragistics WinForms UltraDayView

Tags: winforms, calendar, scrollbar, infragistics, netadvantage

Using Infragistics NetAdvantage for Windows Forms 11.2, I've set up a schedule grid that uses the UltraDayView control.  When there are more rooms (owners) shown than would fit on the form, the horizontal scroll bar will properly show, allowing the user to view the additional rooms.

However, after upgrading to NetAdvantage for Windows Forms 13.1, the horizontal scroll bar no longer shows when there are more rooms than what would fit on the form.  The vertical scroll bar is always shown in both cases.

I've confirmed it's due to the control library upgrade, as no code has changed on this form since upgrading, and using source control to revert to the prior version re-enables the horizontal scroll bar.  I also cannot find any information about this behaviour on the Infragistics website.

Has anyone here experienced this as well, and if so, have you found a workaround?

Comment: From your description this seems to be a bug. The best course of action is to put this question on their support site although many employees of Infragistics check these pages.

Comment: I've done that as well; I'm casting a wider net for the solution in case anyone here has experienced the same issue, and I'll also post the solution here if I get one there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the control and was logged as development issue 143026 and the fix will be in the next service release for NetAdvantage for Windows Forms.  Currently this is scheduled for June 21st.  For update on the service releases you should check the [Infragistics Product Service Release Schedule](http://www.infragistics.com/help/service-releases/).

When the service release is available, you will be able to download it from the [My Keys and Downloads Page](https://www.infragistics.com/my-account/keys-and-downloads/).

Comment: Seen on our support page, and thanks.  That's well within the schedule for our next release.